# Pyramid: getting INI settings filename

Tags: pyramid

I need to take different actions based on what config file is passed at the time the server is started.

I have three config files -- `prod.ini`, `dev.ini` and `test.ini`.

When I do

```
pserve test.ini
```

I want to be able to know, within code, that `test.ini` has been passed. Is there any way to do it?

I checked `config.registry.settings` -- but it does not have anything.

The only other option I have is to specify an `env` directive within the INI files and then access it -- which is easy. But I didn't want to do the extra work and have to remember to do it for every new INI file I create.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WSGI entry point should look like:

```
def main(global_config, **settings):
    """ This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application.
```

If my memory doesn't server me incorrectly, there should be `global_config["__file__"]` which is the configuration INI filename.

However what I usually do is that inside the INI file itself you specify a variable `mode = production` or `mode = test`, etc.

Comment: I would add that you should not have a global mode, but rather one config key for each behavior. For example, `use_email_mock`, `allow_db_reset`, `allow_signup`.